# How to collect many Pandas dataframes into one in loop

Tags: pandas

I try to collect many pandas dataframes into one, in loop/
My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from simpledbf import Dbf5

p = Path("")
df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in p.glob('*.dbf'):
    dbf = Dbf5(i.name, codec = '866')

    t = dbf.to_dataframe()
    print(t)   # prints no empty dataframe

    df.append(t)

print(df)  # prints empty dataframe
```

But i have empty result. 
Where is my mistake?

Comment: I think append returns a new object. You probably have to assign it to df.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[`df.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas-dataframe-append) is not a inplace operation, you must assign back to df.  It returns a modified dataframe.

```
df = df.append(t)
```